# Highlighting a cell when it matches 2 prior cells

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to get a 3rd cell to change colors if this cell and the 2 prior cells have the same response in it. For example if `S133`, `U133` and `W133` all have an `N` in them, I would like for the 3rd `N` cell to highlight a color. What formula would I use?

Comment: that is set in `conditional formatting`